# Databricks Unity Catalog: Query Table of Storage Account in other subscription

Tags: databricks-unity-catalog

I am using Azure and I have `3 subscriptions` each containing a `storage account` and a `databricks workspace`. The storage accounts do `not` have a `public endpoint` and all databrick workspaces are bounded to the `same metastore`.

When creating a `external table` in one databricks workspace, I see the `external table` in the databricks workspaces of the other subscriptions but I can't query it.

**Can I access any data of a storage account without a public endpoint via unity catalog?** Which protocol is used behind the scenes?

**Additional Info:**

I use the Managed Identiy of the Databricks workspace as Storage Credential.